# Cucumber run test: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, automated-tests, cucumber

Hi im trying to run a test with cucumber, but when i try to run anytest, with IntellJ, show me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:1000)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections.max(Collections.java:713)
    at io.cucumber.core.feature.FeatureParser.parseResource(FeatureParser.java:46)
    at java.base/java.util.function.BiFunction.lambda$andThen$0(BiFunction.java:70)
```

my POM:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>messages</artifactId>
      <version>21.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
      <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
          <artifactId>messages</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
          <artifactId>cucumber-gherkin-messages</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
      <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
          <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
          <artifactId>messages</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
          <artifactId>cucumber-gherkin</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
          <artifactId>messages</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
      <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

If anyone can help me, i really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dependencies are inconsistent. You are explicitly excluding transitive dependencies of Cucumber and explicitly including others. You shouldn't do that, Cucumber needs those to function.

I would strongly urge you to invest time in learning how to use Maven (or Gradle) beyond a superficial level. Understanding these tools and the concepts involved can make your life much easier.

For example:

If you want to use Cucumber with JUnit 5 and annotation based step definitions you would declare this minimal set of dependencies in a Maven `pom.xml` file.

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-bom</artifactId>
            <version>7.10.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

By telling Maven what your dependencies are Maven can calculate your transitive dependencies i.e: the dependencies of your dependencies.

This has many advantages. One example would be using the `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` command to will list all dependencies and their transitive dependencies.

```
$ mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< cucumber:cucumber-java-skeleton >-------------------
[INFO] Building Cucumber-Java Skeleton 0.0.1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ cucumber-java-skeleton ---
[INFO] cucumber:cucumber-java-skeleton:jar:0.0.1
[INFO] +- io.cucumber:cucumber-java:jar:7.10.1:test
[INFO] |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-core:jar:7.10.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-gherkin:jar:7.10.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (io.cucumber:cucumber-plugin:jar:7.10.1:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-gherkin-messages:jar:7.10.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.cucumber:gherkin:jar:25.0.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- (io.cucumber:messages:jar:19.1.4:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (io.cucumber:cucumber-gherkin:jar:7.10.1:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:messages:jar:19.1.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:tag-expressions:jar:4.1.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-expressions:jar:16.1.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:datatable:jar:7.10.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-plugin:jar:7.10.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:docstring:jar:7.10.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:html-formatter:jar:20.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (io.cucumber:messages:jar:19.1.4:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:ci-environment:jar:9.1.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test
[INFO] +- io.cucumber:cucumber-junit-platform-engine:jar:7.10.1:test
[INFO] |  +- (io.cucumber:cucumber-core:jar:7.10.1:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.9.1:test
[INFO] |     +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |     +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.9.1:test
[INFO] |     |  \- (org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     \- (org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-suite:jar:1.9.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-suite-api:jar:1.9.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.9.1:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-suite-engine:jar:1.9.1:test
[INFO] |     +- (org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.9.1:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- (org.junit.platform:junit-platform-suite-api:jar:1.9.1:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- (org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-suite-commons:jar:1.9.1:test
[INFO] |        +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:jar:1.9.1:test
[INFO] |        |  +- (org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.9.1:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |        |  \- (org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |        +- (org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |        +- (org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.9.1:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |        \- (org.junit.platform:junit-platform-suite-api:jar:1.9.1:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.9.1:test
[INFO]    +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.9.1:test
[INFO]    |  +- (org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  +- (org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.9.1:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  \- (org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.9.1:test
[INFO]    |  +- (org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.9.1:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  \- (org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.9.1:test
[INFO]       +- (org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.9.1:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]       +- (org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.9.1:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]       \- (org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.933 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-12-28T16:33:23+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note: If you see a transitive dependency listed as "omitted for duplicate" and you have also included it in your `pom.xml`, this inclusion isn't needed. Maven will download it for you.

Also if you are looking to make a fresh start, you could also use the [cucumber-java-skeleton](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton) to start with a working project.