# I am getting initialization error :java.util.NoSuchElementException while running runner file using Junit

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, junit4, bdd

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:970)
at java.base/java.util.Collections.max(Collections.java:713)
at io.cucumber.core.feature.FeatureParser.parseResource(FeatureParser.java:46)
at java.base/java.util.function.BiFunction.lambda$andThen$0(BiFunction.java:70)
at io.cucumber.core.resource.ResourceScanner.lambda$processResource$1(ResourceScanner.java:79)
at io.cucumber.core.resource.PathScanner$ResourceFileVisitor.visitFile(PathScanner.java:75)
at io.cucumber.core.resource.PathScanner$ResourceFileVisitor.visitFile(PathScanner.java:60)
at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2810)
at io.cucumber.core.resource.PathScanner.findResourcesForPath(PathScanner.java:53)
at io.cucumber.core.resource.PathScanner.findResourcesForUri(PathScanner.java:31)
at io.cucumber.core.resource.ResourceScanner.findResourcesForUri(ResourceScanner.java:61)
at io.cucumber.core.resource.ResourceScanner.scanForResourcesUri(ResourceScanner.java:134)
at io.cucumber.core.runtime.FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.loadFeatures(FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.java:62)
at io.cucumber.core.runtime.FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.get(FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.java:45)
at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:156)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:484)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:37)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.createRunner(ClassRequest.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.requests.MemoizingRequest.getRunner(MemoizingRequest.java:19)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:90)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:76)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:513)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

I have been doing many workarounds for couple of days but couldn't resolve this issue. Can anyone please help?

Below are the jars I used.

```
cucumber-core-7.10.1.jar
 cucumber-expressions-16.1.1.jar
 cucumber-extentsreport-3.1.1.jar
 cucumber-gherkin-5.2.0.jar
 cucumber-gherkin-messages-7.10.1.jar
 cucumber-java-7.10.1.jar
 cucumber-junit-7.10.1.jar
 cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.6.jar
 cucumber-plugin-7.10.1.jar
 cucumber-reporting-5.7.4.jar
 datatable-7.10.1.jar
 datatable-dependencies-3.0.0.jar
 extentreports-3.1.2.jar
 extentreports-cucumber7-adapter-1.2.0.jar
 gherkin-5.2.0.jar
 gherkin-jvm-deps-1.0.6.jar
 hamcrest-2.2.jar
 hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
 junit-4.13.2.jar
 selenium-java-4.7.2.jar
 selenium-server-4.7.2.jar
 tag-expressions-5.0.1.jar
```

This is my project folder structure
[folder-structure-image][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/abYF2.png

This is my runner file:
package com.qa.myrunner;

```
import java.io.*;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import com.vimalselvam.cucumber.listener.Reporter;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = {"E:/Programming/LearnAutomation/SeleniumCucumberBDDV2/src/main/java/com/qa/features/SelectFlight.feature" }, 
glue = {"/SeleniumCucumberBDDV2/src/main/java/com/qa/stepDefinitions" }, 
monochrome = true, 
dryRun = false)

public class SuiteRunner {

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cucumber run test: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74941614/cucumber-run-test-exception-in-thread-main-java-util-nosuchelementexception)

Comment: Looks like you are including the dependencies manually instead of with Maven, but the answer is the same. You should learn and use Maven (or Gradle).

Comment: See examples here https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton